# in asp.net input button does not work in chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why this input tag does not work  Chrome browser :

asp.net code :

```
<td><input type="button" value="Go" class="btn" style="width: 40px; color:black;font-weight:normal;" onclick="return getPSAP();" ></td>
```

we used JavaScript method

```
window.navigate("MenuDisplay.aspx");
```

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would help answering the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please post your javascript function getPSAP()

Answer (score 0):

please find :getPSAP() function

```
 function getPSAP()
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById("table_data");
        var str = document.getElementById("<%=txtSAPPCode.ClientID%>").value;
        if (str == "") { return; }
        if (str == "0")
        {
            window.navigate("Menu.aspx");
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.rows.length; i++)
        {
            if (obj.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == str)
            {
                window.navigate(obj.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
                return;
            }
        }
        alert('You are not Authorised to view the same.')
    }
```